# Непонятное поведение конструктора

Tags: c++, qt

В классе главного окна объявляю надпись
    `QLabel *lblStatus;`
В конструкторе класса главного окна инициализирую и добавляю надпись в панель статуса:

```
lblStatus = new QLabel(this);
ui->statusBar->addWidget(lblStatus);
```

Есть функция updateStatusInfo(), которая вызывается в resizeEvent:

```
void MainWindow::resizeEvent(QResizeEvent *event)
{
    Q_UNUSED(event)
    ra->redraw();
    updateStatusInfo();

}
```

в ней выводится информация на панель:

```
void MainWindow::updateStatusInfo()
{

    QString info;
    ...
    //Здесь формируем текст и выводим его на надпись
    lblStatus->setText(info);
}
```

Программа падает на строке `lblStatus->setText(info); , как будто лейбла не существует. Хотелось бы понять, как так получается.

Comment: дебаггер для того и придумали... .

Comment: А указатель то на этой строчке у вас верный? вы дебаггером туда вставали? Если неверный - где теряется или не инициализируется? Тоже дебаггером выяснить. Или у вас ошибка не указателя? В общем телепаты уже на НГ :)

Comment: Событие resizeEvent вызывается раньше конструктора. Как так может быть? С указателями все в порядке.

Answer (score 1):

Все, разобрался. Это не цикл обработки сообщений запускался до конструктора, это функция `showMaximized` вызывала `resizeEvent` и соответственно крэш программы.